# How to copy the output of -text HDFS command into another file?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sequencefile

Is there any way we can copy text content of hdfs file into another file system using HDFS command:

```
 hadoop fs -text /user/dir1/abc.txt
```

Can I print the output of -text into another file by using -cat or any method ?:

```
 hadoop fs -cat /user/deepak/dir1/abc.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

As it's written in the [documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.19.1/hdfs_shell.html) you can use `hadoop fs -cp` to copy files in `hdfs`. You can use `hadoop fs -copyToLocal` to copy files from `hdfs` to local file system. If you want to copy files from one `hdfs` to another then use [DistCp tool](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.19.1/distcp.html).

Answer (score 0):

As a general command line tip you can use `|` to another program or `>` or `>>` to a file, e.g.

```
# Will output to standard output (console) and the file /my/local/file
# this will overwrite the file, use ... tee -a ... to append
hdfs dfs -text /path/to/file | tee /my/local/file

# Will redirect output to some other command
hdfs dfs -text /path/to/file | some-other-command

# Will overwrite /my/local/file
hdfs dfs -text /path/to/file > /my/local/file

# Will append to /my/local/file
hdfs dfs -text /path/to/file >> /my/local/file
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you I did use streaming jar example in hadoop-home lib folder as follow :

```
hadoop -jar hadoop-streaming.jar -input hdfs://namenode:port/path/to/sequencefile \
-output /path/to/newfile -mapper "/bin/cat" -reducer "/bin/cat" \
-file "/bin/cat" -file "/bin/cat" \
-inputformat SequenceFileAsTextInputFormat
```

you can use "/bin/wc" in case you would like to count the number of lines at the hdfs sequence file.

Comment: How is this related to question?

Answer (score 0):

you can use following:

1. ***copyToLocal***
   `hadoop dfs -copyToLocal /HDFS/file /user/deepak/dir1/abc.txt`
2. ***getmerge***
   `hadoop dfs -getmerge /HDFS/file /user/deepak/dir1/abc.txt`
3. ***get***
   `hadoop dfs -get /HDFS/file /user/deepak/dir1/abc.txt`